# Function such that it and its derivative vanish?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a $C^1$-differentiable function such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2(1+|x|)^ndx < \infty$

Are the following two assertions true?

$\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f(x)=0$

$\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f'(x)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\psi$ be the [Bump Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) which is $1$ on $[1/3,2/3]$ and $0$ outside $(0,1)$ and set $f=\sum_{n\ge 0} \psi(2^n (x-n))$. Note that $\text{supp}|f|^2=\text{supp}f$ because each $\psi(2^n(x-n))$ has disjoint support and $|f|^2\le 1$. Then
$$\begin{align} \int_{\Bbb R} |f|^2(1+|x|)^k \text{d}x &= \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n\ge 0} \psi^2(2^n (x-n))(1+x)^k\text{d}x \overset{(1)}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\int\psi^2(2^n(x-n))(1+x)^k\text{d}x \\&\le \sum_{n\ge 0}\int_{(n,n+2^{-n})}(1+x)^k\text{d}x\le \sum_{n\ge 0}\int_{(n,n+2^{-n})}(2+n)^k\text{d}x \\ &\le \sum_{n\ge 0}2^{-n}(2+n)^k<\infty \quad \text{by the Ratio Test} \end{align} $$
Where $(1)$ is justified because $\psi(2^n(x-n))(1+x)^k$ are all measurable. Yet $f(2^{-n}/3+n)=1$ so $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x)\neq 0$. Similarly, the MVT shows there exists some point $c\in (0,1/3)$ where $\psi'(c)=1$, so $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f'(x)\neq 0$ either.

Comment: It's not clear to me that $f$ is even defined over all of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @J_Psi $\psi$ is defined on all $\Bbb R$, in fact, it is $0$ everywhere outside $(0,1)$. Therefore $\psi(2^n(x-n))$ is $0$ everywhere outside $(n,n+2^{-n})$. Since these intervals are disjoint for all $n$, $f$ converges everywhere in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I'm afraid I still cannot see how this function can be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, let alone be $0$ everywhere outside $(0,1)$. The second term in the series for $f$ seems to suggest that the function is $1$ on the interval $(\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3})$.

Comment: @J_Psi $f$ is not 0 everywhere outside $(0,1)$, $psi$ is. We use variations of $psi$ to build up $f$. Think of $f$ as rectangles of height $1$ and base $2^{-n}$ with a spacing of $1$ between each rectangle. Now smooth over the rectangle to ensure $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Is $\psi$ even defined on $(0,\frac{1}{3})$ and $(\frac{2}{3},1)$?

Comment: Oh, or are you suggesting that those are the intervals where the smoothing out is taking place?

Comment: @J_Psi yes, you can take a look at the Wikipedia article explaining Bump Functions.

Comment: One more question, in the second equality above, you don't seem to have taken the modulus-squared of $f$. I assume that this doesn't matter either way. Why is that?

Comment: @J_Psi You are right, it was a typo, but it does not matter because all we need is for $|f|^2\le 1$, which is true because $|f|\le 1$ by construction.